# How to perform If Statement in Field Calculator of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

I have a shapefile containing two numeric fields ("Dist_1" and "Dist_2").  I want a Field Calculation that will populate an additional field ("Result") with one of three answers:

First if Dist_1 is greater than Dist_2 populate Result with 'True' 
Second if Dist_1 is less than Dist_2 populate with 'False'
and Third if Dist_1 and Dist_2 are equal populate with "Equal"

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85487)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Parser:

`Python`

Code block:

```py
def calc(f1,f2):

    if f1 > f2:
        return "True"
    elif f1 < f2:
        return "False"
    else:
        return "Equal"
```

Expression:

`calc(!Dist_1!, !Dist_2!)`

Or graphically (you cannot see all of the code block here unfortunately)

[image]

Comment: PolyGeo thanks - but getting an error 000989 - Parsing error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (line 3).  Can you decode this?!!

Comment: Keep consistent spacing for the if,elif,else statements (2) as well as the return statements (4). Each should be on its own line.