# Creating If Then statement in Field Calculator between 2 values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, if-else

I have a FC with a column for NEAR_ANGLE from the output of the NEAR tool. The angle is displayed in degrees (i.e. -154.67687) which is fine. I am trying to create a column, `HEADING`, that reads this degree value and converts it to either a "North, North-east, South, South-west... etc. whichever direction the near object happens to be from my point.

i.e. If value is between 0 and 90 then East, or if value is between -180 and -90 then South-west

I've searched and tried several examples but none work for me.

Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic If/Then in Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81817/basic-if-then-in-python-parser-of-arcgis-field-calculator)

Comment: What examples did you find, and  what did you try?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99615/writing-conditional-if-then-statements-into-field-calculator-of-arcgis-for-des

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72791/how-to-perform-if-statement-in-field-calculator-of-arcgis-for-desktop

Comment: The geoprocessing message says I have a syntax error in line 1 but I see none. I even tried copy and pasting the code. Still an error

Comment: You need to add the code the code to your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing conditional (if/then) statements into Field Calculator of ArcGIS for Desktop using Python parser?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99615/writing-conditional-if-then-statements-into-field-calculator-of-arcgis-for-des)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago, I wrote this Python function that returns 'E', 'NE', 'N', etc. based on the overall direction of a line geometry (i.e. the direction from its starting coordinates to its ending coordinates).

```python
def determine_arc_bearing(line_geom):
    ''' Determines the cardinal direction of a single arc, determined from its
        two endpoints. The angle is determined by the atan2() function, and
        after some numeric manipulation is then used to select the correct
        cardinal direction from an ordered list of possibilities. '''
    from math import atan2, degrees, floor
    x1 = line_geom.firstPoint.X
    y1 = line_geom.firstPoint.Y
    x2 = line_geom.lastPoint.X
    y2 = line_geom.lastPoint.Y
    xdiff = x2 - x1
    ydiff = y2 - y1
    angle = degrees(atan2(ydiff, xdiff))
    index = int(floor(((angle + 22.5) % 360) / 45))
    cardinal_dirs = ('E', 'NE', 'N', 'NW', 'W', 'SW', 'S', 'SE')  # Order here is critical
    bearing = cardinal_dirs[index]
    return bearing
```

You can adapt the code after the coordinate calculations to suit your own needs. The key part are the 3 lines at the end that calculate `index`, `cardinal_dirs` and `bearing`. You could use a stripped-down version of this function that accepts your NEAR_ANGLE field as the argument in your pre-logic script code:

```python
def determine_heading(angle):
    from math import floor
    index = int(floor(((angle + 22.5) % 360) / 45))
    cardinal_dirs = ('N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW')  # Order here is critical
    bearing = cardinal_dirs[index]
    return bearing
```

And then the expressions for actually calculating `HEADING =`

```python
determine_heading(!NEAR_ANGLE!)
```

Comment: Would this work if the two locations were two separate points instead of a line feature?

Comment: I have an X field for the starting point....From_X   and a Y field ... From_Y.  The near object 's fields are  X..NEAR_X and Y ..NEAR_Y

Comment: @CarlRoss yes, you could modify the function to accept four fields as arguments (instead of one line geometry argument) and use those to set the `x1` (From_X), `y1` (From_Y), `x2` (NEAR_X) and `y2` (NEAR_Y) values. If you do it that way, the math should work as-is.

Comment: @CarlRoss I should add that this will not work well if your X/Y coordinates are unprojected (i.e. in decimal degrees). This is Euclidean math that works well with the assumption of a flat plane, but is unreliable for curved surfaces, which is what decimal degrees represent.

Comment: Forgive me. Im relatively new to this. I do have an angle that is being produced by running the NEAR tool. For example, the output of the angle is -150.265648. Im assuming that this is the angle from my starting point to the near point. Being new and slightly naive, I thought that maybe I could just insert code into the calculator that would take this angle , and return a string depending on which two angles (settings) it fell between.  If it was between zero and 90, then return Northeast...and so on. Im way off here aren't I?

Comment: And these are in decimal degrees

Comment: @CarlRoss I've updated my answer with a function that should work for you directly. You should consider running the Near tool on a projected dataset, in my opinion.

Comment: This works. I appreciate it. Like I said, pretty new to this so Ill definitely look into running the tool as you advised. Many thanks. How to mark as answered?

Comment: @CarlRoss Happy to help. To accept the answer, please click the check mark underneath the answer score and upvote/downvote buttons.